# Stacked bar plot with only the three best

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a `stacked bar plot` with `seaborn` or `matplotlib`. I want to get all my needed information with `.pivot_table` and then I want to filter only the three neighbourhoods with the most counts. But there is an `KeyError: 'neighbourhood'` because neighbourhood is index in df_new.

How could I generate from my `df_new` (**`df.pivot_table` must be**) a stacked bar plot with only the top three neighbourhoods?

```py
d = {'host_id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3], 
     'listing_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'neighbourhood': ['Sofia', 'New York', 'Berlin', 'London', 'London'], 
     'price': [50.0, 60.0, 50.0, 80.0, 90.0], 
     'room_type': ['Private', 'Private', 'Shared', 'Private', 'Shared']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

[OUT]

   host_id  listing_id neighbourhood  price room_type
0        1           1         Sofia   50.0   Private
1        1           2      New York   60.0   Private
2        2           3        Berlin   50.0    Shared
3        3           4        London   80.0   Private
4        3           5        London   90.0    Shared

df_new = df.pivot_table(index='neighbourhood', columns='room_type',
                                             values='price', aggfunc='mean',
                                            fill_value=0.0)
print(df_new)
[OUT]

room_type      Private  Shared
neighbourhood                 
Berlin               0      50
London              80      90
New York            60       0
Sofia               50       0
df_Best = df.groupby(["neighbourhood"])["room_type"].count().reset_index(
                                                     name="count").sort_values(
                                                     by=['count'], ascending=False).head(3)
print(df_Best)
[OUT]
  neighbourhood  count
1        London      2
0        Berlin      1
2      New York      1

df_new.loc[df_new['neighbourhood'].isin(df_Best['neighbourhood'].head(1).values[0])]
print(df_new)

[OUT]
KeyError: 'neighbourhood'

# Because neighbourhood is index in df_new
```

At the end I want something like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `"neighbourhood"` column of `df_Best` to directly index `df_new`. E.g. `df_new.loc[df_Best['neighbourhood'].head(1)]`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = {'host_id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
     'listing_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'neighbourhood': ['Sofia', 'New York', 'Berlin', 'London', 'London'],
     'price': [50.0, 60.0, 50.0, 80.0, 90.0],
     'room_type': ['Private', 'Private', 'Shared', 'Private', 'Shared']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_new = df.pivot_table(index='neighbourhood', columns='room_type',
                        values='price', aggfunc='mean',
                        fill_value=0.0)
df_Best = df.groupby(["neighbourhood"])["room_type"].count().reset_index(
    name="count").sort_values(
    by=['count'], ascending=False).head(3)
df_new.loc[df_Best['neighbourhood']].plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: stacked bar plot]

Note that `df_new` is created via `df.pivot_table(...)`.
If you really want to create the plot purely from `df.pivot_table`, a less readable form would be:

```py
df.pivot_table(index='neighbourhood', columns='room_type', values='price', aggfunc='mean',
               fill_value=0.0).loc[
    df.groupby(["neighbourhood"])["room_type"].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head(3).index]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I looks great.  But I would like to use `df.pivot_table`, how could I do that with that?

Comment: I just updated the answer with a stand-alone version of the code.  The answer was already using `df.pivot_table()`, so I don't understand what you'd like differently.

Comment: You could do `dfp = df.pivot_table(index='neighbourhood', columns='room_type', values='price', aggfunc=['mean', 'count'], fill_value=0.0)` and then `dfp = dfp.assign(tc=dfp.iloc[:, 2:].sum(axis=1)).sort_values('tc', ascending=False)` if there's insistence upon using the `.pivot_table`. @Test However, the count sum can't be aggregated in the pivot_table and additional steps are still required, and this results in multi-index columns which is less ideal.

Comment: @Test Also note that stacking the bars makes the y-axis a bit dubious, especially when one of the room_types isn't present in the data. The y-axis now has "sum of the average prices per room type, using 0 for non-available room types". Using`stacked=False` would give an easier-to-interpret plot.